# Implement "Remember this computer"

Tags: security, web-applications

What are the different methods to implement "Remember this computer"? I am trying to work on capturing the user's machine information such that if the user logs in next time into the application, it will identify the machine and not challenge the user with secret questions.

Comment: There's no way to identify client machine (thank gods). Your functionality could be implemented by sending a cookie with long expiration date.

Comment: You mean setting a permanent **cookie**, at least to identify the machine? Another idea might be to use **OpenID**, leave the authentication to a third authority. Combined they would work like Stack Overflow itself.

Comment: @JoopEggen: stack overflow also work on cookie based system, if you clear them you need to login again.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi you're right.

Comment: I cant use open ID but I read something about using flash cookies or Local Shared Objects (LSO) but have a hard time to get any reading materials on that. Does anyone know if its good or bad when compared to permanent cookies. Thanks.